# Is there a way to encapsulate Vuex store inside Vue plugin (its install function)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

- I have a plugin and this plugin uses Vuex

```js
// plugin.js
import Vuex from "vuex";
import store from "./store.js";

export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    const storeInstance = new Vuex.Store(store);
    Vue.prototype.$store = storeInstance;
  }
};
```

- And in that plugin I import a store object.

```js
// store.js
export default {
  actions: {
    SOME_RANDOM_ACTION({ state, commit }) {
      console.log("some random action");
    }
  }
};
```

Dispatching actions and using state is fine and works as expected.

But when I add this plugin to another Vue instance that uses vuex, store object re-initializes with new state.

```js
// index.js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import App from "./App.vue";
import plugin from "./plugin.js";

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(plugin);

new Vue({
  // WARN when i uncomment this next line of code Vuex gets re-initialized with new object
  // store: new Vuex.Store({ state: { hello: "hix" } }),
  components: {
    App
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

When you uncomment store initialization, store that was defined in the plugin is now not available.

Currently, I have these solutions in mind:

1. Export my plugin store object to index.js main app, and use this store as a module.
2. Use some other state management.

Is there a way to use Vuex inside my plugin?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-sanne-67yej?file=/src/main.js:0-371

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuex plugin uses `store` option to assign store instance to `Vue.prototype.$store`, similarly to your own plugin.

If the intention is to use multiple stores, their names shouldn't collide. The key is to name your store object inside plugin something other than `$store`

```
Vue.prototype.$myPluginStore = storeInstance;
```

But this still doesn't encapsulate `$myPluginStore` inside the plugin, as it is accessible within the app.

```js
// App.vue

computed: {
    appState() {
      return this.$store.state;
    },
    pluginState() {
      return this.$myPluginStore.state; // this is now accessible within the main app
    }
}
```

It would be a reasonable solution to allow a store to be used as a module of existing store instead of creating a new store, but only when used within one app and not when used as a plugin for a package.

The main problem is that default store instance (`$store`) can make use of Vuex helpers - `mapGetters`, etc.

Comment: This turns out to be the actually simple solution is to name store in my plugin something other than _$store_, thanks and [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-monad-3f7q7?file=/src/plugin.js) is working example

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the install method exposed by the plugin to get access to the store - which should be accessible from your other component.

One possible solution is to register your store in the `index.js` like:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store";
import plugin from "./plugin";

Vue.use(plugin);

new Vue({
  store,
  components: {
    App
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

You can then expose `$doStuff()` and get access to `$store` in the `plugin.js`

```
export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$doStuff = function (payload) {
      this.$store.dispatch("SOME_RANDOM_ACTION", payload);
    };
  }
};
```

The store instance is accessible from your plugin or all the other components.

You can see a [working sample here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-sanderson-fuz5h?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: That's the exact solution I was talking about in my question, the question is how to encapsulate a store inside a plugin and not to export it into the main app.

Comment: Sorry for that, glad you have clarified. What are you trying to achieve with this? Is it to create a store instance that is only local to that plugin? Kindly clarify and then I'll be glad to assist you

Comment: Yes, exactly that, I want to have store local only for my plugin.